# How to store value referenced with pointers in variables?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, casting, scanf

Actually I have a string looking like this : `"1,22,333,,55555,666666,7777777"`

From this string I have created two array :

- One with the size of each parameter. For the given exemple it looks like this : `[1;2;3;0;5;6;7]`
- The second with the pointer that reference the beginning of each parameter.
  For the given exemple it looks like this :

```
    ["1,22,333,,55555,666666,7777777";
    "22,333,,55555,666666,7777777";
    "333,,55555,666666,7777777";
    ",55555,666666,7777777";
    "55555,666666,7777777";
    "666666,7777777";
    "7777777"]
```

The parameters can change in length and in type but not in order.
So i want to store them with typecasting for those concerned

I have tested to `sscanf` each index of the pointer array but it seems not working

```
char* format = strcat(strcat("%", params_sizes[0]), "u");
strutest.un = sscanf(params_pointer[0], format);
```

Do you have any idea that can help me ?

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are trying to do. What do you mean by " So i want to store them with typecasting for those concerned"

Comment: "...but it seems not working" Well, okay but... please describe what is going wrong

Comment: "_The parameters can change in [...] in type_" - What? What does _type_ mean to you?

Comment: I have a structure of parameters that that differ in types (float, uint8_t, uint32_t, int16_t, char[]) and I want to fill those parameters accordingly with the value I have.

Comment: As I know the size of the value I want to scanf my pointers with a specific scanf format that I must create and it doesn't want to be create

Comment: I absolutly don't understand what you're trying to do. From what I see, you can use strtok (if you can't / shouldn't modify the string, use strdup) and that's all. What's with the type changing ? Please post a valid code so that we can understand ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
char* format = strcat(strcat("%", params_sizes[0]), "u");
```

is wrong.

The prototype for `strcat` is

```
char *strcat(char *restrict dest, const char *restrict src);
```

where `dest` is the **destination**, i.e. (a pointer to) the object where the concatenated string is stored.

So looking at your code:

```
strcat("%", params_sizes[0]
       ^^^
       dest !!!
```

you are trying to store the result in a string literal. That won't work (modifying a string literal in undefined behavior).

You need something like:

```
char format[1024] = "%";  // Sufficiently big char array that can be modified

strcat(strcat(format, params_sizes[0]), "u");
```

BTW: Also consider `sprintf` instead of nested `strcat`